# Ending program after character detection

Tags: python

Trying to end this after the first vowel is detected, but I am getting all of the consonants in the word.

```
word = input("Enter a word: ")

while len(word) != 0:
    cons = ""

    for x in word:
        if x.isalpha() and (x not in "aeiouAEIOU"):
            cons += x
        else:
            print('No more consonants')
    
    print(cons)

    word = input("Enter a word: ")
```

This prints every consonant, not just the letters before the first vowel.
Example: If typing 'Thud' output will be 'Th'

Comment: `else: break`…?!

Answer (score 0):

Add a break statement when a vowel is detected. The code should be modified like:

```
word = input("Enter a word: ")

while len(word) != 0:
    cons = ""

    for x in word:
        if x.isalpha():
            if x not in "aeiouAEIOU":
                cons += x
            else:
                break
        else:
            break
    
    print(cons)

    word = input("Enter a word: ")
```

Comment: The second `else: break` is nonsense.